# Is VB6 IDE supported in Windows Vista x32?

Tags: vb6

Are VB6 IDE and VB6 applications supported in Windows Vista x32 ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Support Statement for Visual Basic 6.0 on Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008
 and Windows 7** 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx

Comment: It appears that they'll ensure it works, but that's about as far as their commitment goes.

Comment: @rwmnau: What else would you expect? VB6 is dead; it's no longer being updated or maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Not after April 8, 2008. The runtime is still supported though. [Details from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbrun/ms788708.aspx).